# Using readline() and split()

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader, readline

The code below is mostly self explanatory. However, I am having trouble in two cases:

1. The `while` loop does not exit even with the command line is left blank.
2. If the input is `test t1` the `key` variable is supposed to be "test" (using `System.out.println(key)`) does that, but, it still doesn't enter the `if` condition for some reason.

   ```
   String[] broken_text = null; String text = "";
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   while((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {     
     broken_text =    text.split(" ");
     String first_key = broken_text[0];    
     if (first_key == "test") {
           //some statements    
      }
   }
   ```

I am not sure why this is happening, any help regarding the same will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use equals() to check string equality.

```
if (first_key == "test") {
         //some statements
    }

should be

if (first_key.equals("test")) {
         //some statements
    }
```

your `text` will never be `null` because you declared it as

```
String text = "";
```

thus your while loop would be an infinite loop

change

```
String text = ""; 
to
String text = null;
```

or if you wanna leave your `text=""` string as empty string.

use

```
while(!(text = reader.readLine()).isEmpty())
```

Comment: To farther expand on Gangn...thqiqdwedwe's answer, check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 1):

The loop does not end because a blank line causes `readLine()` to return an empty string, not `null`.

The comparison fails because Strings must be compared with `equals()` not `==`

Answer (score 1):

The `String` `text` will never be `null` in this case. You can use:

```
while (!(text = reader.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be your edited code:

```
String[] broken_text = null;
String text = "";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while((text = reader.readLine()) != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
    broken_text = text.split(" ");
    String first_key = broken_text[0];
    if ( "test".equals(first_key)) {
         //some statements
    }
}
```

The reason changed `(text = reader.readLine()) != null` to `(text = reader.readLine()) != null && !text.isEmpty()` is because `readLine()` returns `null` when it encounters end-of-file as the first character, and it returns "" (empty string) when the first character is encounters is `\r` (carriage return), `\n`(line feed) , or `\r\n`(carriage return followed by line feed). And you must always check for `null` before checking for `isEmpty()`.

On *unix / Linux* console end-of-file is `[ctrl][d]` and on *DOS* it is `[ctrl][z]`

Note: In case you want to read input from a file (where you are more likely to get an end-of-file) instead of console, then your `reader` will be initialised like this:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\a1.txt"));
```

(assuming your input data is in file: *"d:\a1.txt"*.)